# How to convert map keys to string without set?

Tags: scala

I have `val states = Map("AL" -> "Alabama", "AK" -> "Alaska")`

I want to convert keys of `states` to `Seq(String)`, but I get `Seq(Set(String))` instead.

I tried

```
Seq(states.keys.toString)
res3: Seq[String] = List(Set(AL, AK))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to have duplicate keys in a map. That's why `keys` returns `Set[K]`. See the definition of `keys` below

```
  /** Collects all keys of this map in a set.
   * @return  a set containing all keys of this map.
   */
  def keySet: Set[K] = new DefaultKeySet

  def keys: Iterable[K] = keySet
```

`.keys` actually return `Iterable[K]`, you can `.toList`/ `toSeq` on `Set` to change the data-structure.

```
scala> val states = Map("AL" -> "Alabama", "AK" -> "Alaska")
states: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(AL -> Alabama, AK -> Alaska)

scala> val stateNames = states.keys.toList
stateNames: List[String] = List(AL, AK)
```

or

```
scala> val stateNames = states.keys.toSeq
stateNames: Seq[String] = Vector(AL, AK)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a `Seq[String]`

```
Map("AL" -> "Alabama", "AK" -> "Alaska").keys.toSeq
res0: Seq[String] = Vector(AL, AK)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not Python. `Seq(set)` does not "convert" a set to a sequence. Instead, it constructs a single-element sequence with the set as the single element.

You want

```
states.keys.toSeq
```